# Adjusting fill=white in Tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, nodes

In the MWE below, I'm looking for a way to adjust the `fill=white` boundary so that it doesn't interfere with the two arrows. If I remove the `fill=white` stipulation, there is ONE dot in the dotted arrow that gets in the way of the 3; is there a way to remove that one dot, presumably by adjusting the boundary of `fill=white`?

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{Alegreya}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.45]

\node (x) at    (0:0)   {$x$};
\node (y) at    (0:6)   {$y$};
\node (q) at    (0:9)   {$q$};

\path[->,dashed]    (x) edge [bend right] (q);
\path[->,dotted]    (y) edge [bend right] node [midway,fill=white] {\tiny 3} (q);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kill the `\node`'s `outer sep` and `inner sep`; also, control the position using `pos` key; I used `0.5` so it's the same as your original `midway`:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{Alegreya}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.45]

\node (x) at    (0:0)   {$x$};
\node (y) at    (0:6)   {$y$};
\node (q) at    (0:9)   {$q$};

\path[->,dashed]    (x) edge [bend right] (q);
\path[->,dotted]    (y) edge [bend right] node [pos=0.5,fill=white,inner sep=0pt,outer sep=0pt] {\tiny 3} (q);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

You can also move it a little with `above` and similar keys:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{Alegreya}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.45]

\node (x) at    (0:0)   {$x$};
\node (y) at    (0:6)   {$y$};
\node (q) at    (0:9)   {$q$};

\path[->,dashed]    (x) edge [bend right] (q);
\path[->,dotted]    (y) edge [bend right] node [pos=0.5,fill=white,inner sep=0pt,outer sep=0pt,above=2pt] {\tiny 3} (q);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I need it "in" the arrow for reasons not shown in the MWE, but your top answer is perfect. Out of curiosity, is there a reason you used `pos=0.5` instead of `midway`? Thanks so much!

Comment: @Sam You're welcome! I used `pos=0.5` instead of `midway` just to make explicit an option allowing you to control the position if you wanted to; if you want it just in the middle, `midway` is perfectly safe.